# Buddy pokemon: when fed to spawn on the map, how long will it last?

Tags: pokemon-go

When you feed your buddy pokemon so it spawns on the map, it will do so for a set time. But how long does it last?

I also heard poffins double the time, is that true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When feeding your buddy berries so that it will walk beside you, it will last for a total of 3 hours ([Source](https://www.eurogamer.net/pokemon-go-buddy-adventure-play-excited-6002)). And yes, it is true that using a poffin with double this time to 6 hours.

> [Using a poffin], your buddy will also stay full, stay on the Map, and stay Excited for longer
>
> [Source](https://niantic.helpshift.com/hc/en/6-pokemon-go/faq/2147-what-is-a-poffin)

Comment: You said stay full (i guess the food meter), stay on the map and stay exited like its 3 different things but I have the feeling all 3 the same. Like as soon as the meter runs out you will lose your buddy on the map, and being exited I guess is the double love for actions, but that happens only when fed with a poffin?

Comment: Niantic's support hasn't always been the greatest when it comes to details, but staying full and staying on the map is more-or-less synonymous thing. Using a poffin completely fills the hunger meter, which when full, allows them to appear on the map. Once the hunger meter empties, then they return to their original state. 
Being excited is a little different, which - as you said - doubles the number of heart you can receive. You can achieve full excitement without using a poffin, but it's a butt-and-a-half to obtain